# gitlab wiki: How to add images by storing them locally

Tags: gitlab

I am using gitlabs wiki page. I am using markdown.

I want to add some images to the wiki.

```
![test]("./image.png")
```

But how can i store the `image.png` in the wiki

Comment: as far as I know, the wiki itself is a git repo too. So just clone it and push the image

Comment: You use the "attach" functionality when creating the page in the UI -- or commit the file using git. Both have the same effect.